How can I start to use the LuaLaTeX engine with luaotfload
When I try to compile the emoji package code as below with engine lualatex for the first time as below, and the test code is as follows:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{lipsum,zhlipsum}
\usepackage{emoji}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\emoji{joy}\emoji{+1}

\zhlipsum[2]\emoji{family-man-woman-girl-boy}\emoji{woman-and-man-holding-hands-light-skin-tone-medium-dark-skin-tone}
\end{document}

Then I compile that in the terminal with command lualatex mwe.tex(the tex file name is mwe.tex)
,then show the following and get stuck for more than half an hour.
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.

I don't think that is just a several patience, is there any solution to use lualatex for me? or how could I know the percentage of the command luaotfload?
Thanks!

After I execute the command luaotfload-tool -u -vvvv proposed by Ulrike Fischer in the command line, and the fonts goes smoothly until the following message, and it get stuck, is that because the .ttc font? How to solve the problem?
<plenty of ttf fonts infomation, omitted here>
luaotfload | db : Loading font c:/windows/fonts/rock.ttf
luaotfload | db : Loading font c:/windows/fonts/rockb.ttf
luaotfload | db : Loading font c:/windows/fonts/rockbi.ttf
luaotfload | db : Loading font c:/windows/fonts/rockeb.ttf
luaotfload | db : Loading font c:/windows/fonts/rocki.ttf
luaotfload | db : Loading font c:/windows/fonts/rogfonts-regular.otf
luaotfload | db : Loading font c:/windows/fonts/sansserifcollection.ttf
luaotfload | db : Loading font c:/windows/fonts/sarasa-superttc.ttc

And then get stuck as the sarasa-superttc.ttc file.

That is indeed unusual, it can take 5 minutes or so but I have never seen it take half an hour.

I don't know what happens to my computer..../(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

How old (or, rather, how slow) is your computer? On my MacBookAir with an M2 chipset and 16 MByte RAM, the luaotfload-tool utility tends to take at most 2 or 3 minutes to create a hash file the first time a feature-richt opentype font file is accessed. (By feature-rich, I mean mostly that the font file can contain several thousand, or even ten-thousand, glyphs.) Thirty minutes or more is much too long.

It bought half of year ago... with AMD Ryzen 9 7940HX with Radeon Graphics, the situation is a little crazy about it.  In my region, the access of the github is a little slow, is that to be blame for?

Are you saying that you store the hash file and/or the underlying opentype font files on GitHub?

run on a command line luaotfload-tool -u -vvvv  you can then see where it hangs (and some fonts can be large!).

@Mico No, I didn't put the hash/otf files online, I just guess that because I found the Development url: https://github.com/khaledhosny/luaotfload in texdoc lualatex...

@UlrikeFischer So weird? In my command line it says that there is no command named luaotfload? Is my installation of TeXlive2024 broken partly?

sorry, I meant luaotfload-tool -u -vvvv

@UlrikeFischer I've corrected the comment

The first time LuaLaTeX compiles a document that uses a previously unused Opentype font, it invokes the luaotfload (or luaotfload-tool) utility to create a hash file. A "hash file" is an informal term for a look-up database; creating a hash file makes subsequent uses of the font much, much faster. So, where does your system store the hash files? On its local harddisk or on GitHub?

I found the root font of stuck! the command luaotfload-tool -u -vvvv get stuck with the following:   luaotfload | db : Loading font c:/windows/fonts/sarasa-superttc.ttc Is the .ttc font caused the block?

@Mico All the fonts files and hash files is stored on my local harddisk.

So what was you earlier reference to GitHub about? You have me thoroughly confused...

Sorry, I got confused by the Development url: https://github.com/khaledhosny/luaotfload in lualatex docs, then I misunderstanding that the luaotfload-tool maybe generate fonts from github, which my network access is a little slow for some reason.

luaotfload has no problems to handle ttc fonts, but I found some google hits which seem to indicate that this one is a few hundred MB large. So perhaps you really needs lots of patience. Or you should blacklist it, see the luaotfload documentation.

I will consult the docs, maybe it takes a little time, thanks to your sincere and prompt response!

It's actually the LARGE font family of sarasa-superttc.ttc that to be blame for. After I add the sarasa-superttc.ttc appended to the luaotfload-blacklist.cnf at the root of C:\texlive\2024\texmf-dist\tex\luatex\luaotfload to blacklist it, both the luaotfload-tool -u -vvvv and lualatex <filename> executed smoothly in about 2 minutes, it helps me a lot, I am extremely grateful of your help!
